# Sql update query with multiple condition

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have two columns. Attributename and AttributeValue.
And i should update AttributeValue to this Attributename where MAsterid=somevalue

suppose if i select Attributename and attribute value for master id 1
the table will show likke

```
Master ID    attributename     attributevalue
----------   --------------   --------------
   1            MODE_CODE             BARGE
   1            SAP_CODE              1
   1            DESCRIPTION           B
```

I can update using

```
UPDATE CORE.MasterAttr
SET AttributeValue = (
    CASE AttributeName
        WHEN 'DESCRIPTION' THEN 'Barge'
        WHEN 'SAP_MODE' THEN '01'
        WHEN 'MODE_CODE' THEN 'B'        
    END
) WHERE MasterId=1
```

BUT Problem is now i know the Attribute names.

but in real scenario ,we are buildng dynamic attribute names.so we dont know how many atribute names will be there for each master id.

so how can we write procedure or query for dynamic values please.

please help me on that.

Comment: that's what parameters/variables are for....

Comment: in this what you want to insert in attributevalue? 
is attributevalue static or it also dynamic?